# Can secrets be stored in the Code.gs file?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons

Since we can get a user's email address from the Gmail Add-on API, I'm wondering if we need to authenticate users with OAuth before they interact with our external service or whether we can rely on a stored secret to ensure that requests made with the user's email address are actually coming from a user using the Gmail add-on.

Since app scripts run on Google's servers and aren't modifiable by the user, we could just HMAC the request bodies in the requests to our external API with a secret stored in the Code.gs file. This would (maybe?) ensure that it this endpoint was actually being hit by Google and that the person making the request was the owner of the given email address.

For this approach to work though the secret in the code would actually need to stay secret, otherwise anyone could just hit that endpoint with any email address and post data on behalf of other users. So does this approach actually work, or is there another similar solution that might be feasible?

Otherwise we can just implement OAuth, but if there is a simpler approach that's secure then that would be preferable.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your external API just need an API key(a secret) to authorize users. You can definitely store it using [Properties Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/) .

But the tricky part is that different user might have different API keys. To solve it , we could ask the user to enter the API key in the UI (can't be masked, though). 
This is a very simple approach.

However, I would recommend using OAuth , as it is a more cleaner way.